# How to add elements to row of ListView programatically?

Tags: android, listview

So I have a base row that is basic template that is shown at the start when the rows of the list view is created, but each row has a button that adds new elements to the row clicked in the list view for example adding a EditText the problem is that each time I scroll down and then come back to the row I added things, it is created again and the elements I added are erased. I know this is happening because my application is calling the method `getView()` each time the row is shown and it is instantiating the view again with the R.layout.listview_row that is where I have the basic row template. So I want to know how can I make sure that the elements in the row are saved.

This is my adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;

    ArrayList<String> mDataSet;


    public ListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> mDataSet){
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mDataSet.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mDataSet.get(i).hashCode();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        final View rowView=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null,true);;

        TextView exercise_text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_text);
        exercise_text.setText(mDataSet.get(position));

        Button btnEliminarRow = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminarRow);
        btnEliminarRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDataSet.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        Button btnNuevaRow = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnNuevaRow);
        btnNuevaRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addView(rowView);
            }
        });

        addView(rowView);

        return rowView;
    }

    // Helpers

    public void addView(View view) {
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_sets);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_row , null);
        Button moreOptions = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.moreOptions);

        ll.addView(v);

        moreOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ll.removeView(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So as you can see in getView I have a listener that in each click of a button I call the method addView, this method inflates an xml that contains some new elements that I want to add to the basic row created. The problem as I said is that as `getView()` is being called each time an reloading the views the elements I added are being overridden and the layout is inflating the view again as the starting state. I've tried using an if and checking if convertview is not null then not inflate the view again but this doesn't seem to work, because it's like the convertview is being reused and so its being called the `addView()` for the same view many times.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new item to the dataset and notify the adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged`. Also, I would implement the view holder pattern.

[Here some examples.](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Now, back to your code, you should implement a method called: `addItem(String item)` that adds an element to `mDataSet`. After that you notify the adapter.
Something like:

```
public void addItem(String item) {
    if (mDataSet == null) mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    mDataSet.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

After that, improve your `getView()` method to use the [ViewHolder Pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) and an [example](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview).

Comment: Yes I know you have to notify the adapter when a new row is added to the listView and I have this method  implemented in a new activity, what Im talking about in the problem is that I add elements to the already added list view row so for example add programatically a edit text to a editText, see the addView method.

Comment: You should implement this with conditions in the same getView().. Maybe just hidding/showing them there will do the trick. If the view is too complicated you can maybe even migrate to a recyclerview.

Comment: I dont think hidding them is a good idea because I dont know how many times the element is going to repeat. I've already tried a recyclerview and had some similar issues.

Comment: Still, adding it like that doesnt seem like a good idea. What do you want to accomplish exactly?. You can even share the xml that you are inflating.